# C- RPC on linux ( Bubble sort)

Tags: c, rpc

I want to create RPC application on Linux using rpcgen.
It is a Bubble Sort.
I used this tutorial: [CLICK HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoArvQ0sp_w)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{

int i, j, temp;

for (i =0; i <array_size; i++)
{
    for (j =0; j<array_size-1; j++)
    {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[j+1])  {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
            numbers[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}

int main(void)
{
int array[10000];
int i;

for(i=10000;i!=0;i--)
{
    array[i-1]=i;
}
bubbleSort(array,10000);
for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",array[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

And my question is what should I put into "file_name.x" and "file_name_client.c" and "file_name_server.c" that it will work.

Thanks for each tip ang answer.

Comment: ` "file_name.x" and "file_name_client.c" and "file_name_server.c"`??? what are those?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! . Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: BTW, are you aware that would be quite stupid because extremely inefficient? And you mean RPC/XDR or ONC/RPC, not just RPC!

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare a function, which takes a variable-length integer array and returns the same:

**IDL-code for bubblesort.x:**

```
typedef int sortarray<>;

program BUBBLESORT {
    version MESSAGEVERS {
        sortarray doBubbleSort(sortarray) = 1;
    } = 1;
} = 31337;
```

You of course cannot sort it in place, so you have to return the sortarray to have the result transmitted over the network.

Now compile it with `rpcgen bubble.x`

Since C doesn't know native variable length arrays, the type `sortarray` will expand to:

```
typedef struct {
    u_int sortarray_len;
    int *sortarray_val;
} sortarray;
```

and the function prototype for the service:

```
extern  sortarray * dobubblesort_1_svc(sortarray *, struct svc_req *);
```

Now implement the function dobubblesort_1_svc, which should sort the array in `sortarray` using your sort function and then returning the result array (if you sort in place, you can also directly return the first argument to `dobubblesort_1_svc`)

**Comment:**

SunRPC is antiquated and a pain, however. You should really use modern RPC-mechanisms whenever possible (SOAP. XMLRPC, ORB, whatever)

Comment: *From OP*: "Too much errors. Can you send: "bubblesort_client.c" and "bubblesort_server.c" CODE after compile "bubblesort.x"? Because when I did:" make -f Makefile.bubblesort" were too much errors.". *My reply*: Sorry, I gave you a kickstart, but I won't write your code completely. Try as good as you can, if you still have errors, extend your question including these.